# How to reset tables in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a development version of salesforce that I'd like to delete all the records from. My analyst is telling me that to do so manually will take a week, or we can refresh it which will take minutes to a week.

It seems to me that there must be a better way of doing this. In SQL, I'd make a list of tables to truncate and dynamically truncate each one. Is there some way to do this with salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

It won't take you a week to refresh a sandbox, usually only takes 30 minutes. You can also write an execute anon script that will delete data from your tables

```
List<YourObject> objectData = [SELECT ID FROM YourObject];
delete objectData;
```